# Css animation clock with starting position set in js?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, css-animations

I want to make a simple clock in Css animation but showing the real time, I try to set a starting time and then rotate the hand.

But there is a problem that when i try to rotate it for 360 degrees in 60 seconds (in case of seconds hand) it is counting the 60 seconds for rotate 360 not towards the starting point but towards the angle of 0 degrees. So i am not sure what should be the correct approach for this.

My css code:

```
  .s-hand {
  height: 30px;
  -webkit-animation: rotor 60s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: rotor 60s linear infinite normal;
  animation: rotor 60s linear infinite normal;
}

  @-webkit-keyframes rotor {
   to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

And js/ts:

```
var d = new Date();

var s = d.getSeconds() + Math.floor(d.getMilliseconds() / 1000);

let shand = document.getElementsByClassName('s-hand') as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;

    if (shand.length != 0) {
      shand[0].style.transform = "rotate(" + s * 6 + "deg)";
    }
```

So:

1. starting position is being set correctly
2. animation is being run correctly
3. only the time of full rotation of hand is not correct

Codesnippet:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bvEPWv

As you can see the hand is moving too slow because it counts 60 seconds toward the 0 degree, not towards starting point(which is set in js)

Comment: please, add html and set all as full working snippet to see the issue and have the chance to edit it easily

Comment: @JoelBonetR i have added a snippet with explanation what's going on